# WebSockets and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Recently lots of online games such as http://agar.io have been utilising the relatively new feature of WebSockets to create real time mmog's. My question is how can I create a node js program which can handle connections from browsers using WebSockets?

Example Browser Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebSockets</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
            //some message sending over here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Node.js Code:

```
//what goes here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer To These Websites:

https://davidwalsh.name/websocket

http://socket.io/

And you may need to install socket io as a npm package.